# Is there a way to set Windows Phone 7 Emulator some settings before started? As Theme, region, language

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I need when the emulator starts to start with different locale and also in light theme which is not the default. Is there any way to do this in some settings file or something like that?

Searched over the net but nothing found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

General settings for the Windows Phone emulator are stored in XDE-based board configuration files (*.decfg) that can be specified as parameters when you launch an XDE instance. Those files are located here:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\1.0** (for 64-bit systems)

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft XDE\1.0** (for 32-bit systems)

You will see that there is **config_board0.decfg** and **config_board1.decfg** - both are nothing more than XML files with a different extension. There, you can configure:

Whether to show the debug console or not (in case you don't want to dig through the registry)

- Zoom factor
- RAM Size
- Displacement
- GPU Configuration (e.g. FPS
  throttling)
- Orientation

The language is specified by the **/language** parameter that is passed to the emulator. The LangID is, in fact, the LocaleID (LCID) - you can get a full list [here](http://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-Codes.asp?s=hexadecimal). Decimal values from that table should be used.

If the LCID you passed is not registered on the device, it will default to **English - United States** (en-US - 1033).

A simple launch string could look like this (with parameters):

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   XDE\1.0\XDE.exe" /decfg D:\Tempor
>   ary\config_board1.decfg /vmid
>   {6db75612-361e-4c8f-8aaa-307a312c39c6}
>   /binfile "C :\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
>   Phone\v7.1\Emulation\Images\WM70C1.
>   en-US.bin" /language 1031

Where 1031 (for the language) represents **German**.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The language passed to XDE is emulator-specific and has nothing to do with the OS. The only supported language right now is **English - US (1033)**.

Comment: I'll try this and see what happends

Comment: I hit the launch string in run and got file not found. Also tell me, WM70C1.en-US.bin sounds like for english do i need to replace it german version. if yes where can i find it.

Comment: Do you have the SDK installed? Are you sure the path was correct for all components?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot set phone theme and locale programmatically but you can just open your Windows Phone 7 emulator and go to Settings and from there set the light theme as you wished for and also set it to different locale.

I would always recommend developers to keep their physical phone and emulator on different themes and possibly in different locales. Then you constantly test your app against different configurations.